# Is there a way to put an EC2 instance part of ASG in Standby?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way with Terraform to put an EC2 instance, part of an auto-scaling group, in Standby mode? I am able to find in the documentation only creation of ASG and AMI, but not the actual step of setting an instance in Standby mode or InService.
I am looking into creating a project that creates an AMI of our EC2 instance. It's attached to an auto-scaling group with a Classic load balancer. So I want to set it to Standby mode first, create the backup ami (which causes a server restart) and then set the instance back to InService in the ASG.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to develop your own [local-exec](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) script with AWS SDK to achieve that.